# if $K(a)=K(b)$ are $a$ and $b$ conjugates of the same minimal polynomial in $K[x]$?

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $F$ an extension of $K$, we know that if $a\in F$ and $b\in F$ are conjugate elements then with respect to some minimal polynomial in $K[x]$ then $K(a)=K(b)$. Is the reverse direction true as well? I.e if  $K(a)=K(b)$ are $a$ and $b$ conjugates of the same minimal polynomial in $K[x]$?

Comment: By conjugate do you mean that $a$ and $b$ have the same minimal polynomial over $K?$

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(1+\sqrt{2})$.